# Managing both streaming and plain text output from OpenAI

Tags: frontend, backend, openai-api, langchain

If you have ever used perplexity.ai then you will see that when you ask a question, it first streams the output and then it dumps the links, instead of streaming them. I am trying to figure out how to do that in Langchain. I have use cases in which i just want to stream, or i just want to dump my answer, or do both. I can figure that out on the backend, but how do i configure the frontend?